# Agregar una columna nueva a partir de otra en Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Muy buenas, (empezando con spark).

estoy intentando una columna nueva a partir de otro tipo `integer` para que con valores inferiores a 10, me indique 0 en la columna nueva o sino crear 1.

Pero debo estar haciendo algo mal, y me indica:

```
"No se puede convertir la columna en bool: por favor use '&' para 'y', '|' para 'o', '~' para 'no' cuando construya expresiones booleanas de DataFrame.
```

```
def apto():
  if df1.G3 < 10:
     return 0
  else: 1
df1 = df1.withColumn("apto",apto())
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

- Utilizar la sintaxis de PySpark
- Definir la funcion en Python y utilizar UDFs, que permite utilizar la funcion en pyspark

---

Sintaxis PySpark
Utilizarias simplemente la funcion when:

```
from pyspark.sql.function import  when
df1 = df1.withColumn('apto', when(df.G3<10, 0).otherwise(1))
```

---

UDFs
Primero defines la funcion en Python

```
def apto(a):
  if a < 10:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1
```

Luego importas la funcion UDF y la aplicas sobre la funcion inicial

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
apto_udf = udf(apto)
df1 = df1.withColumn('apto', apto_udf(df.G3))
```